# AD B2C ROPC JavaScript Token Retrieval

Tags: javascript, azure, cors, blazor, azure-ad-b2c

I have Azure AD B2C and a Blazor Server-side app with a Login page. I created a ROPC Custom Policy and tested with Postman and it retrieves the token with the claims correctly. But when I want to retrieve the token from the browser with JavaScript to the same endpoint/url I get an error from CORS that my response is blocked. How I solve this? I'm missing any configuration on either the Blazor app or the AD B2C?

Comment: I have a feeling this is not a supported feature :\ There _might_ be some switch in the app registration to enable it but I'm a bit skeptical. I've never seen any CORS settings in B2C.

Comment: If you can't do the call from front-end, you might need a proxy API that makes the call to B2C from its back-end so CORS is not involved.

Comment: @juunas  Please, can you suggest a link/docs to create that Proxy on the back-end? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ROPC in browser is not supported due to CORS policy. The result is expected.

Please refer similar [GitHub issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/39795#issuecomment-538043176) which helps in understanding more.